# Grouping cities by name with different formats

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that returns user information, which includes city and country. The problem is users have entered their city names into a text field, so the formatting differs.

> Washington D.C.
>
> Washington, D.C.
>
> Washington, DC
>
> New York
>
> NY

Is there anyway to determine that "New York" and "NY" are the same city? I don't need to use a group by in my query, the cities can be parsed in PHP.

**EDIT**: I should have mentioned that the damage is done, I inherited this database with 15,000 user records. Cities are entered through some corporate profile anyway.

Comment: In our site, we disallow the users to enter their own city names.  They enter in a ZIP Code, and then the city and state are auto-filled.  Maybe that's something you can look into?

Comment: Here is a suggestion: Why not create a static list to be chosen in PHP instead of text field for the city and use that to be inserted into your DB

Comment: This is why most of the time this stuff is a dropdown list. So the formatting doesn't change from a fixed list. Your only option is probably to do something like create a table of aliases that tie "New York" to "NY" and then you could join on that table to find other spellings of the same city.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a client database with 15,000 users, so having the city entered by a dropdown was outside my control. And there is sadly no zipcode field.

Comment: Best thing you could do is possibly use "LIKE" for things like multiple version of Washington DC, as for NY == New York, going to have to make sure that everyone who put NY meant New York

Comment: You could normalize your city fields in order to obtain only one possible occurrence per city and then modify the form so the user is obliged to choose via autocompletion inserting then only coherent city values.

Comment: I'll suggest to **first** change the form as soon as possible (dropdown list or whatever other option you can use to avoid more of those entries), then prepare some queries in order to update the fields of city and countries, you must start by grouping by those fields to recognize the ones you need to `update` and after that do it